How do we enable Granular consent and verify the mobile app
We are not able to Set the parameter 'enable_granular_consent' to true when calling the Google OAuth authorization endpoints . As the parameter is not available for Mobile Google APIs. As per the document, the parameter is available for Server-side web Apps. Can't find a way to enable Granular permission and check the app in sandbox. And we can't find 'googleapis.com' anywhere in our code base. Does that mean we are not using any of the googleapi?

Following the documentations and tried to find out if we are using any of the googleapis, by checking the code base.

Tried to Enable the Granular consent through code to find out how our mobile app works. Can't enable it through code.

Expecting a clear documentation on how to enable the consent for mobile apps and test the app locally.



You are correct. Not all SDKs support 'enable_granular_consent' parameter, but some support free form parameter inputs when making the authorization request. Again, not all SDKs support that. If these are not the options, you can always create a new Client ID and use it only for testing since all newly created Client IDs would have granular permissions enabled.
See Test your updated application on handling granular permissions section.
